# spring-kafka-test polling records from topics

Tags: spring-kafka

I am using `KafkaTestUtils` to fetch the consumer records for validation along with other utilities which is handy, however I am seeing when I am making a call to `KafkaTestUtils.getSingleRecord(..,...)` which seems fetching all the records from the topic which was sent from other test methods (one example : `verifyEmptinessErrorMessageInTopic()`), and it's failing at the `assertion` at `getSingleRecord` method because the count is not `1`. In my listener of actual business logic which is a manual ack and I do `acknowledgment.acknowledge()` to commit the offset but in test code, which seems fetching all records from the topic instead of last one. I also tried the `consumer.commitsync()` which normally do the offset commit and that's not working as well.

Am I missing any configuration in test util here? Thanks for the input.

```
private static KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate;
private static Consumer<String, Object> consumerCardEventTopic;
private static Consumer<String, Object> consumerCardEventErrorTopic;

@BeforeClass
public static void setup() throws Exception {
    // Producer Setup
    Map<String, Object> producerConfig = KafkaTestUtility.producerProps(kafkaEmbedded);
    ProducerFactory<String, Object> pf = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfig);
    kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(pf);

    // Consumer for cardEventTopic setup
    Map<String, Object> consumerConfig =
            KafkaTestUtils.consumerProps("cardEventGroup", "true", kafkaEmbedded);
    consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    ConsumerFactory<String, Object> cf = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfig);
    consumerCardEventTopic = cf.createConsumer();
    kafkaEmbedded.consumeFromAnEmbeddedTopic(consumerCardEventTopic, cardEventTopic);

    // Consumer for cardEventErrorTopic setup
    Map<String, Object> consumerConfigError =
            KafkaTestUtils.consumerProps("cardEventErrorGroup", "true", kafkaEmbedded);
    consumerConfigError.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    consumerConfigError.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    ConsumerFactory<String, Object> cf1 = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigError);
    consumerCardEventErrorTopic = cf1.createConsumer();
    kafkaEmbedded.consumeFromAnEmbeddedTopic(consumerCardEventErrorTopic, cardEventErrorTopic);
}
@Test
public void verifyProcessedSuccessfully() {
    kafkaTemplate.send(cardEventTopic,  accountValid());
    ConsumerRecord<String, Object> received =
                    KafkaTestUtils.getSingleRecord(consumerCardEventTopic,cardEventTopic);

    assertThat(received).isNotNull();
    assertThat(received.value()).isInstanceOf(String.class);
}

@Test
public void verifyEmptinessErrorMessageInTopic() {
    kafkaTemplate.send(cardEventTopic, accountInValid());
    ConsumerRecord<String, Object> received =
            KafkaTestUtils.getSingleRecord(consumerCardEventErrorTopic,cardEventErrorTopic);
    assertThat(received).isNotNull();
    consumerCardEventTopic.commitSync();
}

@Test
public void testMethod3(){
}
@Test
public void testMethod4(){
}
```

Comment: You need to consider to have a clean `cardEventTopic` before sending records into that in the `verifyEmptinessErrorMessageInTopic()`. On the other hand what is the point to play with `getSingleRecord()` if you have a listener which simply can be used to cover the whole business logic from sending to receiving.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense,  and I saw the ```getSingleRecord()``` method gets all records with poll and verifies if it's 1. To check this I have written an utility to get the records and check the necessary logic.